# ForEach Loop Export to CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am working on creating a script that will output all the computer names and models to an excel file. The code works without the Export-Csv pipe but I can't figure out how to create the excel file. If I take out the loop and use only one computer with the Export-Csv it also works fine.

```
#Query AD
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -searchbase "DC=domain,DC=org"

#loop
foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
$comp=$computer.Name
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $comp | Where-Object {$_.model -like "*G2*"} | Select-Object Name, Model  | Export-Csv "C:\User\xxxxxx\Desktop\8200s.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
}
```

Comment: I couldn't say how to do this specifically, but I use a PS script that pulls all services from all computers in a specified OU and dumps them to a CSV and it builds an array in the loop and then dumps the array to a CSV when complete.

Comment: Here's the script I use. You should be able just to modify the PARAM and For loop to get what you need: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ADComputerServiceAccoun-8bb81568

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move the `Export-CVS` out of the loop, and use `Foreach-Object` so you can use the pipeline.

```
# Query AD for computers
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -searchbase "DC=domain,DC=org" |
ForEach-Object {
    $comp=$_.Name
    # return name,model for all G2 computers
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $comp |
        Where-Object {$_.model -like "*G2*"} |
        Select-Object Name, Model
} | Export-Csv "C:\User\xxxxxx\Desktop\8200s.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 1):

With some of your suggestions and a little more thought, I was able to figure this out. We created an Array and and object, wrote information to an array and then to the file. I was able to get the export and then had to put forth some more effort to figure out all the errors with down computers that would make the script run very slow. Below is what we used.

## Query AD

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Continue"
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -searchbase "OU=TechDepartment,OU=Workstations,DC=domain,DC=org"
$OurArray=@()
$firstObject = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $firstObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value ""
Add-Member -InputObject $firstObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value ""

#loop
foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
$comp=$computer.Name
If(Test-Connection $comp -count 1 -Quiet)
    {
    #Successful Ping
    Write-Host "$comp"
    try{
    $firstObject = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $comp -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Name, Model | Where-Object {$_.model -like "*8200*"}
    $OurArray += $firstObject
    }catch { "$comp RPC is Down"}
    } 
    Else
    {Write-Host "$comp is offline"}
    }
 $OurArray | Export-Csv 8200s.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Either answer works. @Zoredache's answer is a bit more PowerShell-y in that it uses the pipeline and less code. But that is mostly a style thing. You are seeing the PowerShell provides multiple ways to get to a solution which makes it more powerful in the long run.